# How can i generate Opentok Session Dynamically for and android? using Java server sdk?

Tags: python-2.7, opentok, tokbox

can anyone help me to create OpenTok SessionID and Token for my app and I just tried python sdk sample Helloworld app from **opentok** repository and 
followed steps from the repository and still unable to create session. the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 16, in <module>
    session = opentok.create_session()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/opentok/opentok.py", line 266, in create_session
    raise AuthError('Failed to create session, invalid credentials')
opentok.exceptions.AuthError: Failed to create session, invalid credentials
```

I had API_KEY and API_SECRET for the project. Is there anything to setup further with the **OpenTok Account?**

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

No there is nothing else that you need. I just ran through the whole process outlined in the [HelloWorld sample](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Python-SDK/tree/master/sample/HelloWorld). The only way I get that error message is if the API_KEY and API_SECRET values aren't set properly. Make sure that you are setting the API_KEY and API_SECRET correctly (using export) and that you are getting the correct values from the [Account Portal](https://tokbox.com/account/) for "API KEY" and "SECRET" under your project once you have logged in.